# Understanding "find longest word in string" code

Tags: javascript

```
function findLongestWord(str){
    str = str.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (i = 0;i < str.length; i++){
        if (longest < str[i].length){
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(longest);
    return word.length;
}
```

I don't understand the use of `var longest = 0;` and `var word = null`. I only understand the use of "split", "for", and "if".

Why is the following:

1. `longest = str[i].length` Is this same as `0 = str[i].length`? If yes, why set it to 0?
2. `str[i] = word` Is this same as `null = str[i]`? As I know null means "empty".

What is the logic here?

Comment: What??? try to re explain your problem / question please.

Comment: Does the code actually work?

Comment: I can't understand `word = null` either, setting `word` to empty string would make the code work even if `str` contained spaces only, or was an empty string.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid hm...what is the logic of "0 = str[i].length"?A length of a word = 0??and what does "null" mean here. (sorry im not a native Eng speaker)

Comment: @EricJ. yes. this is an exercise on freecodecamp.I tried it and it passed.

Comment: What are you trying to find? the longest word or the count of the longest word? nevertheless check this implementation; it is more readable: http://jsfiddle.net/xgcrxu8g/1/

Comment: General advice: when you don't understand something, don't hesitate to run the code in debug mode (Chrome, Firefox, Firebug etc. have one built it, learn to use them) and/or print variables using `console.log(someVariable)` for instance. Finally have a JavaScript reference handy. I personally like the [Mozilla Developer Network JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_instances)

Comment: @DavidCastro thx,there is still a same question in the code,"why using zero",now im reading answers the other gave me. :)

Comment: @pyb thx for yr advice ^^

Comment: @CYCoA: Because you'll assume that the first word in the string is the longest; In case they only provide only one word. Basically you assume the first one is the longest and then you iterate over until you find a bigger one.

Comment: @DavidCastro GOOD (can i +1 a comment? lol) ty sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` splits the string up into a JavaScript array (kind of like a list where each word is one term in the list).

Then the for loop cycles through the array. In this for loop `i` represents the current permeatation (i.e. the first time the loop is gone round `i` will be 0, the second it will be 1 and so on).

Thus, `str[i]` gets the current word (in the current permeatation of the loop) and `.length` gets the length of the word. The `longest` variable is initally set to 0 as not words have been entered. Then, if the current word is longer than the current value of the `longest` variable, the variable  is set to a new variable of the length of the current word.

In the same way `word` is set to null initially as there is no longest word yet. If a new longest word is found `word` is set to that word.

Hope this makes sense, if not let me know what you're still having trouble understanding and I'd be more than happy to explain further :)

Comment: @stephen.vakil If you just +1ed my answer, would you consider accepting it please.

Comment: I know, but I was directing the question at the asker.

Comment: Why you've addressed the comment to stephen.vakil then?

Answer (score 2):

Values are assigned from right to left, initially ,
longest is equal to 0,
then below command makes it equal to str[i].length(right to left assignment)

```
longest = str[i].length
```

(here str[i].length is right value so its value will be assigned to longest)

hence it is not same as 0 = str[i].length
  similarly

```
str[i] = word
```

makes str[i]  equal to word not null = str[i]

left value is called lvalue,and from wikipedia LValue is "In computer science, a value that points to a storage location, potentially allowing new values to be assigned"

Answer (score 1):

`str = str.split(" ");` 
This separates all of the words out into an array.

`var longest = 0;`
This will store the number of letters in the longest word.  It is initialized to zero because it hasn't started looking at the words yet.

`var word = null;`
This will store the word that has the most number of letters.  It is initialized to null because it hasn't started looking at the words yet.

`for (i = 0;i < str.length; i++){`
this loops through each word

`if (longest < str[i].length){`
This checks if the current word in the loop is longer (has a longer `length`) than the longest word we have found so far.  Initially this will always be true because the first word is always the longest word and will be longer than 0 in length.

`longest = str[i].length;` 
this keeps track of the length / number of characters in the longest word we have found so far.

`word = str[i];`
this keeps track of the longest word we have found so far.

`console.log(longest);`
This will display in the javascript console the length of the longest word found

`return word.length;`
This will return to the caller the word that was the longest found

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLongestWord(str){            //define a function
    str = str.split(" ");                 //split the string by " " to get an array of the words
    var longest = 0;                      //initiate a variable to store the length of the longest word and set it to 0 (because no words are tested yet)
    var word = null;                     //initiate a variable to store the longest word. Better change this to "var word = '';" so its a string
    for (i = 0;i < str.length; i++){     //iterate through the array of words
        if (longest < str[i].length){    //test if the current word is longer than the longest yet tested word
            longest = str[i].length;     //if its longer store the length of the current word in "longest"
            word = str[i];               //and the actual word in "word"
        }
    }
    console.log(longest);                //log the length in the console
    return word.length;                  //and return the length of the word
}
```

I've done some small optimization on your function:

```
function findLongestWord(str){
    if(typeof str != "string")
        return 0;
    str = str.split(" ");
    var word = "";
    for (i = 0;i < str.length; i++){
        if (word.length < str[i].length){
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(word.length);
    return word.length;
}
```